# How does the constant proportionality balance an equation?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, dimensional-analysis, physical-constants

The Newtonian universal law of gravitation,

> Every object in the universe attracts every other object with a force that is proportional to the product of their masses and inversely proportional to the square of the distance between them

Therefore, $F=GMm/r^2$ where $G$ is the universal gravitational constant that has been identified to have a value of $6.67 \ 10^{-11}\mathrm{\ N\ kg^{-2}\ m^2}$ by Henry Cavendish.

To convert a proportion to an equation, there is an inclusion of a constant

> Reason: To balance the segment at the left to the segment at the right thereby, comprehension of a constant in an alleged equation.

In a general perspective of equations, How is a proportionality constant able to balance an equation?

To the public, I request to answer as per the following divisions of uncertainty over this concept.

1. How do we define a certain value to the proportionality constant?
2. How does it balance the equation?
3. What difficulties did the discoverer face when he tried to define or understand the nature of the proportionality constant?

Comment: 25 years ago, John Walker of Autodesk did an amateur version of the Cavendish experiment: https://www.fourmilab.ch/gravitation/foobar/

Comment: @PM2Ring Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

> 1)How do we define a certain value to the proportionality constant?

This is done experimentally. We take many different objects at different sizes and distances and we measure the gravitational force between them. Then, for all of these objects, we plot $F$ on the vertical axis and $Mm/r^2$ on the horizontal axis. Then the slope of the resulting line is $G$.

> How does it balance the equation?

The phrase “$a$ is proportional to $b$” means that there is some constant $k$ such that $a=kb$ for all $a$ and $b$. Furthermore, if $a$ has units of $[a]$ and $b$ has units of $[b]$ then in order for the units to balance we see that $[k]=[a]/[b]$ where $k$ has units of $[k]$.

> What difficulties does a person face when he tries to define or understand the nature of the proportionality constant?

That is a case by case question. Not all students will have the same difficulties. For the discoverer, the only difficulty is experimental: how to measure the various quantities with sufficient accuracy and precision. Once that is done then the analysis is straightforward

Comment: In the last question, it wasn't about the difficulties faced by the students but, the struggle faced by the discoverer. Thank you for your answer and for editing the question.

Comment: @PledgeLurzow I edited the answer accordingly. You should probably edit the question to clarify your intent

Comment: Yes, I'll. Thank you.

Comment: But can you feel any attraction with tree or Apple? Of course not. But in reality there is but too negligible. Can we do experiment for plotting force vs mass or distance(without massive things like earth)? I believe we can.  since the force is too negligible so how would you measure force for collecting data(for finding gravitational constant)?

Comment: @BillyIstiak this was first done in the Cavendish experiment of 1797 and 1798

Answer (score 0):

Suppose I have a graph , where i compare the values x and y
And as you can infer , the graph forms a linear relationship with between x and y , meaning function of x = y , here this constant is " 2 " , x+2=y when x is 0 , y = 2  and similarly henceforth .

[image]

So now if i compare it with physics , In the Force formula ,**Gravity is proportional to mass of the objects**,**Gravity is inversely proportional to the distance between the centers of the objects.**

and  this leads to

**F= $Gm1m2/r^2$**

**But Why "G "**

1. Firstly mass of the objects , the distance are all in a linear proportional relationship or inversely proportional relationship with each other , doesn't always imply they are exactly equal to the " variable or gravity " they are proportional to .
2. Secondly , this begs for something that can balance the 2 sides making them equivalent which is " the constant of proportionality "
3. For different equations , different constants are required to balance the equation , like Plank's constant , Coulomb constant's and others
4. That constant can also be equal to 1 , For eg : F= kma where k = 1
5. Constant is just a number with no nature
6. How do we get the value of it well that require a bit of basic algebra
   for eg : **F= $Gm1m2/r^2$**
   then,
   G= $Fr^2/m1m2$

I hope this answers your questions :)

Comment: Aarushi Agarwal, Thank you for your answer.